# Estimating the mean when a few points in either tail are grouped into <a or >b?

Tags: estimation, mean

I have a data set with approximately 150 observations.  The data is measured to the nearest tenth.  However, a few points on the left are measured as <50 and one on the right as >650.  What is the best way to handle these observations if I want to estimate the mean?

Comment: this is a *censoring* problem.  You're going to have to make some assumptions about the shape of the tails of the distribution ... can you give a little more context?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there is no way to estimate the mean under this situation.

In practice, check the # of cases with <50 or > 650 among 150 obs. If > 30 cases, I will give up. If not too many, for example, < 10 cases, try to find the reasons of this censored values.

Method 1: If the instrument cannot measure when the value is < 50 or > 650, I would replace < 50 by 25 and > 650 by (650 + highest possible value)/2.

Method 2: Draw a histogram with the cases with true measured value. Check what kind of distribution seems fit the histogram. Estimate the parameters of the distribution based on data. Derive the mean from estimated parameters.